# url change but still on the same page with routing angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular4-router

I'm trying to do this example with angular 4 in my project.
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-routes

[image]

how to change the URL but still on the same page

Comment: post your code here

Comment: How do you want to change the URL? Manually in the browser URL bar, or clicking a link or from code?

Comment: I do not have code yet
I want to know how to do it
you can offer me a tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, well this is not a great question.

Did you read the tutorial? If yes then what is the problem?

1. You need to configure your `Routes` array of `Route` objects:

   ```
   const routes: Routes = [
     { path: 'lazysalim', component: LazySalimComponent }
   ];
   ```

   `Path` is a string representing the route in url and `component` is the associated Component you want to display when on this url.
2. Add it to module (probably `app.module.ts`) imports via `forRoot` method:

   ```
   imports: [
     ...,
     RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
   ]
   ```
3. You need to add `<router-oultet></router-oultet>` into your template. This acts as an anchor, the Component associated with the matching URL will be displayed below this anchor.
4. You need a button or something for navigation to those paths. You can use

   ```
   <a [routerLink]="['lazysalim']">
   ```

   You'll be navigated to url/lazysalim` as a button. Or

   ```
      this.router.navigate(['lazysalim'])`.
   ```

   I hope it's not too long for you :\